# Can my family leave Istanbul Ataturk Airport during layover to Toronto?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, istanbul

My family, including children, are traveling to Toronto and have a layover at Istanbul Ataturk Airport for 18 hours. We want to go out to the city and be back to the airport to catch the Air Canada flight to Toronto. We are Indians and carry Canadian PR Cards.

Comment: be sure to read the other Istanbul-tagged questions for details on how you can get a free tour of the city during your layover, or a free hotel room. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Being from India, you need a visa to enter Turkey. Having an additional visa or residence permit from an OECD country like e.g. Canada, you are entitled as an Indian citizen to apply for a single entry eVisa valid for up to 30 days if you fulfill a few additional requirements: https://www.evisa.gov.tr/

The visa fee is 43 US$ per person.